# Link to automatically import a public calendar into Yahoo Calendar?

Tags: calendar, yahoo, subscriptions

I have created a public calendar and want to let the users subscribe to it using Yahoo Calendar.

Instead of having the users copy the calendar's URL and paste it into their calendar, I'd prefer to have a link so they can click on it and automatically subscribe to my public calendar within their Yahoo Calendar account.

Is there any way to do this? 
Thank you